# How to mkdir and switch to new directory in one line

Tags: function, shell, mkdir

I have been using the linux console for some time now. One thing that irritates me is that every time I create a new directory using `mkdir` I have to `cd` to change to it. Is there a single command solution to create and switch to the directory just created?

Right now I do:

```
mkdir php5
cd php5
```

can I do:

```
mkdir -someswitch php5
```

I want something simple and clean. A good example is `git branch somebranch` which makes new branch and `git checkout -b somebranch` which makes and switches to new branch.

Comment: Interesting, but I doubt there is. I don't see anything on `man mkdir` or `mkdir --help`.

Comment: You could write a simple shell script to do that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The portable way to do this is with a shell function--not a bash function (using bashims like `function`). Put this in the relevant `.profile` for interactive use:

```sh
 mkdir () {
    case $1 in
       (-c) command mkdir -p "$2" && cd "$2";;
       (*)  command mkdir "$@";;
    esac
 }
```

This adds the `-c` option to `mkdir` for interactive use. Without `-c` the utility acts as it always does.- And note the quoting of `"$2"` so this works with directories with white space in their name.

Comment: But wouldn't it call itself recursively _ad infinitum_?

Comment: @rodrigo No, due to the `command`, which is the POSIX way to express "I want to execute the simple command of that name." This skips any alias or function of the same name, should one be defined. See also http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/command.html

Comment: What is the distinction between a "shell function" and a "bash function"?

Comment: @WilliamPursell A bash function uses bashisms, like the `function` keyword used in another answer, while a shell function does not.

Answer (score 11):

Found some magic:

```
mkdir foo && cd $_
```

Comment: this should be on top

Answer (score 3):

nothing prevents you from creating your own alias or small script

```
mkdir $1 && cd $1
```

Comment: Well, a small script is not as easy as it seems. Upon exiting the script, the PWD would be restored.

Comment: `mkdir -p` is much better.

Answer (score 3):

Or you can use ';' to separate commands, like:

> mkdir php5.3 ; cd php5.3

Comment: This will give you two errors if creating the directory fails.

Answer (score 0):

this is what I've been using, not sure if it's in best practices but it works.

```html
function mk() {
    $file = $args[0]
    mkdir $file | cd
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can define a function in bash to do this:

```
function mkcd() {
    mkdir $1 && eval cd $1
}
```

Comment: It prevents expansion of the argument before it's passed to `cd`. This will allow it to work with directory names that contain weird characters.

Comment: But `$1` is expanded before eval is executed. This can't possible do what you think it does.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff: Sorry, I don't get it. IMO, for that you should use quotes: `mkdir "$1" && cd "$1"`. If something, `eval` will make impossible to `cd` into directories with `$` in their name.

Answer (score -1):

A close answer that can help. It is easy to type.

```
 mkdir php7 && cd !$
```

Comment: I wonder why this is not working on my shell. I have a bash shell though.